XVBA Live Server connects VSCode to Excel VBA successfully, but with Windows Script Host Errors
I've successfully connected VSCode to my Excel VBA (365), but I get errors when saving the VSCode file or click "Refresh Macros"

I followed the directions here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=local-smart.excel-live-server.
I can download and upload macros to VBA.
Sometimes it creates new Modules (in this case Module1, Module11, etc.) but they are identical, as if the connection uploaded the macros more than once.



Everything seems to work correctly, but having to close all of the popups is annoying. Plus it points to some misconfiguration somewhere.

All of my files are on the hard drive folder and NOT in a OneDrive folder.

I'm not using version control (git).

I have reviewed previously asked SO questions, but none of them address this problem.

I think I could probably check a settings box to hide this error, and I will if I have to, but I'd rather figure out what is happening, first.


